# Calculating proportion to find sample size

Tags: sample-size, proportion, error

I have population, and I need to find a sample size using the equation

```
MoE = 1.96*/sqrt(p(1-p)/n * (N-n)/(N-1))
```

I know all values except n (obviously) and p...I am supposedly able to get a value of p from this information

> Calculate the required sample size that would need to be distributed among survey interviewers if you do not want to allow more than 3% margin of error for all percentages calculated from the sample

Any ideas of how to find the value of p?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you misunderstood the question. When it asks: "Calculate the required sample size" this means that the value of interest is $n$ and not $p$. The trick here is that you need to find a single value of $n$ that works for all possible values of $p$.

Since we are interest in finding $n$ we should isolate it in the expression for $MoE$:

$$n = N\left(1 + \frac{MoE^2(N-1)}{1.96^2p(1-p)}\right)^{-1}$$

I strongly encourage you to derive yourself the previous expression. Maybe I did something wrong :)

If we knew $p$ than all we have to do is compute the value given by the previous expression and select the first integer grater than the resulting value. But since we do not know $p$ we need to find a value of $n$ that works for all $p$.

Note that we can write $n = N*f(p)$ where $f(p) = \left(1 + \frac{MoE^2(N-1)}{1.96^2p(1-p)}\right)^{-1}$ and now it is clear that the correct value of $n$ is
$$n = N*\underset{0\leq p \leq 1}{\max}f(p)$$

But now we need to find $\underset{0\leq p \leq 1}{\max}f(p)$. First we note that $p(1-p)$ has a maximum in $p = 1/2$, consequently $1 + \frac{MoE^2(N-1)}{1.96^2p(1-p)}$ has a minimum at $p = 1/2$ and finally $\left(1 + \frac{MoE^2(N-1)}{1.96^2p(1-p)}\right)^{-1}$ has a maximum at $p = 1/2$.

After all of this we get that the value of $n$ that works for all $p$ is

$$n = N*f(1/2) = N\left(1 + \frac{4MoE^2(N-1)}{1.96^2}\right)^{-1}$$

Comment: Mur1lo makes a good point.  You can get a conservative required sample size by taking p=1/2.  Sometimes there is prior information that allows you to choose a p different from 1/2.  One way is to do a small pilot study and use the result to determine the sample size you will need.

Comment: Your equations indicate that you have a finite known population size N and you need to fina a sample size n<N that proviides a sufficiently accurate estimate of p.  You did not mention this.